# what is an efficient query for this task

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data file that looks like this

```
item_id  |  status
1        | null
2        | null
2        | new
3        | new
4        | null
4        | new
5        | null
```

Notice that item 2 and 4 have both 2 status: null and new.
I want to create a query that would extract only item_id with 1 status, which is null. So, i want my query to extract only 1 and 5.

I ended up doing this, but this doesn't look efficient:

1.List items with null status

```
create table query_1 as
select * from table1 where status = 'null';
```

2.List item with new status

```
create table query_2 as
select * from table1 where status = 'new';
```

3.select all results from query 1, excluding any id found from the results of query 2

```
select * from query_1 where item_id not in (select item_id from query_2)
```

Am I over thinking this? Is there a simpler query that can accomplish this?

Comment: First you have to check for null values with `IS NULL`. `=null` or `='null'` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check for null values with `IS NULL`. `=null` or `='null'` won't work.

```
SELECT item_id, MAX(status)
FROM table1 
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING MAX(status) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

select item_id
from table1
group by item_id
having count(*) = 1 and status is null

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_id FROM items
WHERE status IS NOT NULL
    AND item_id NOT IN 
        (SELECT item_id FROM items 
            WHERE status IS NULL
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self-join`. What you need to do is remove the item_id's having `new` values. The remaining entries would be would you want. So you can frame your query as such :

```
SELECT  item_id,
        status
FROM    tableName
WHERE   item_id NOT IN (SELECT  item_id
                        FROM    #tab
                        WHERE   status = 'new')
```

You can see this here -> [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f1d5d/1)

Answer (score -1):

You could use DISTINCT in this instance

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM items WHERE status IS NULL;
```

Comment: This would still return items with both null and another status